# Google Translate V2 Sample Code doesnt work as expected

Tags: python, google-api, google-translate

I tried the Python sample code provided on Google Translate, which allows text translation

I encounter the following error while trying the sample python code for google Translate, taken from here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translating_text

```
dailydiy@linuxbox:~$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/dailydiy/WrittenAudio/credentials/credentials.json"
dailydiy@linuxbox:~$ python3 testtranslate.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtranslate.py", line 2, in <module>
    translate_client = translate.Client()
  File "/home/dailydiy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v2/client.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._connection = Connection(self, **kw_args)
  File "/home/dailydiy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v2/_http.py", line 35, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My requirements.txt file has the following entry

```
google-cloud-translate==2.0.0
```

My code is exactly same as the sample code

```
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
translate_client = translate.Client()

if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
    text = text.decode('utf-8')

# Text can also be a sequence of strings, in which case this method
# will return a sequence of results for each text.
result = translate_client.translate(
    text, target_language=target)

print(u'Text: {}'.format(result['input']))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(result['translatedText']))
print(u'Detected source language: {}'.format(
    result['detectedSourceLanguage']))
```

It seems the API and the sample code are not in sync, and it fails at the line which tries to initialize the client.  I know the error means that there is a mismatch in the number of arguments, but i cant seem to understand where the arguments are.

Comment: If you try pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage?

Comment: pip install --upgrade google-cloud-translate

Comment: Unable to recreate this issue. The code above works just fine.

Comment: Will try the recommendation in the comments and get back. Does it have to do with the export of credentials to the env?

Comment: I tried pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage and the error went away. why does that work? How does it solve the Issue with the translate API?